# Start *.exe programs on remote computers

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch file to start and stop a program that normally can be executed from the run line.  I have many computers so this would be tedious to say the least.

I can't seem to get this to work:

```
wmic /node:ipaddress process call create "cmd.exe c:\\somefolder\\someprogram.exe -stop"
```

Comment: Why are you using cmd.exe?  If your program has a stop switch you would just use: `"c:\\somefolder\\someprogram.exe -stop"`

Comment: Have you looked at PsExec?

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow `cmd /?`, use `/C` or `/K` switch:

> ```
> Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter
>
> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
>     [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
> /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
> …
> ```

Use  something like `set "ipadr=192.168.1.7"` and then

```
wmic /node:%ipadr% process call create "cmd.exe /C c:\\afolder\\aprogram.exe -stop"
```

or

```
wmic /node:%ipadr% process call create "cmd.exe /C \"c:\\afolder\\aprogram.exe -stop\""
```

or, if path to program contains space(s):

```
wmic /node:%ipadr% process call create "cmd.exe /C \"\"c:\\a folder\\aprogram.exe\" -stop\""
```

or, if a parameter supplied to program contains space(s):

```
wmic /node:%ipadr% process call create "cmd.exe /C \"c:\\afolder\\aprogram.exe \"-stop\"\""
```

Please note that I use a little shorter names to keep scrollbar-free command lines (as far as possible).

I'm not sure about double backslash(es) in path; on my Windows, single backslash(es) suffice, e.g. as follows:

```
wmic /node:%ipadr% process call create "cmd.exe /C c:\afolder\aprogram.exe -stop"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using `create` when you're wanting to `terminate`:

```bat
WMIC /Node:<server/ipaddress> Process Where "ExecutablePath='C:\\afolder\\aprogram.exe'" Call Terminate
```

Or possibly:

```bat
WMIC /Node:<server/ipaddress> Process Where "CommandLine='full command used to start aprogram.exe'" Call Terminate
```

Comment: @Compo, I assumed the `-stop` they were using in their example was a command line argument the program understood. If that was the case then that in theory should be the more graceful way to stop the program.